# How could I improve getting a List<MyEnum> based on the state of a checkbox?

Tags: c#, data-structures, blazor

I have 6x checkboxes, which represent filters and are booleans. These filters type are represented by an enum. I need to get a List depending on the state of the checkboxes and I'm trying to do it the right way.

Currently I have my 6x checkboxes, which are all boolean:

```
bool checkbox1Filter1
bool checkbox2Filter2
//...
```

I have an enum which looks like this with 6x values:

```
public enum MyFilters : byte
{
Filter1 = 12,
Filter2 = 30,
...
}
```

I currently have a function which adds my filters in a list depending on the state of the checkboxes:

```
function List­<MyFilters> GetMyFilters()
{
var lst = new List<MyFilters>();
if(checkbox1Filter1) {lst.Add(MyFilters.Filter1)}
if(checkbox2Filter2) {lst.Add(MyFilters.Filter2)}
...
return lst;
}
```

Basically I would like to completely get rid of that function and do something smarter with less 'if' everywhere. Could a Dictionnary<MyFilters,bool> do the trick ?